# Elasticsearch/Kibana Unindexed field cannot be searched

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I'm having some trouble in querying  / filtering data on kibana with respect to a `geo_point` field that is indexed.

Here is a relevant section of the mapping template:

```
"dstGeoLocation": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
"srcGeoLocation": {
        "type": "geo_point"
},
```

The ingestion happens okay, since the data ends up in ES and am able to view it in Kibana like so:

[image]

[image]

0,0 is the default that has been given.

However, in Kibana, I still get a message that this is an unindexed field and hence is not searchable.

How do I remedy this situation?

I have already tried to:

1. Remove and reload the index mappings
2. Remove and recreate the kibana index pattern (there is no manual refresh in v7.13)

Version of ES and Kibana: 7.13.12

Comment: can you show the error that you are getting in Kibana as screenshot?

Comment: Hi Mark! I've cross posted the same in the ES forums as well. Added the screenshot from there. Kibana does not have a "refresh index" button anymore. At least I am not able to find it

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just fixed the error you are showing by clicking the small refresh button up right in Stack Management > Kibana > Index Patterns > (select/create some pattern)
[IMGUR Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izX2E.png)
So give it a try.